# xcodebuild exited with code 65 on "npm run tauri ..."

Tags: ios, angular, tauri

I´m using the tauri-app v2 alpha to generate native android and ios apps out of an angular webapp. The android and macos ways work fine, but on generating my ios app via:

```
npm run tauri ios build
npm run tauri ios dev
```

I get the following error:

```
Compiling mobile-app v1.0.0 (/%pathToMySrc%/src-tauri)
    Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 5.66s
       Error [tauri_cli_node] Operation not permitted (os error 1)

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
        PhaseScriptExecution Build\ Rust\ Code /%pathToMySrc%/src-tauri/gen/apple/DerivedData/mobile-app/Build/Intermediates.noindex/mobile-app.build/release-iphoneos/mobile-app_iOS.build/Script-FB82E9A2CD95CB44B10A2F24.sh (in target 'mobile-app_iOS' from project 'mobile-app')
(1 failure)
       Error command ["xcodebuild"] exited with code 65
```

I have seen that this is a known problem by other users and tried their solutions mentinoned on stackoverflow and other sources. This is was I´ve done so far:

1. changed owner and rights of the given shell script
2. executed the shell script out of build context
3. clearified that provisioning profiles are valid
4. removed the build folder and pod-related files to gen fresh ones
5. changed some variables as mentioned in other treads to this issue
6. used Legacy Build Options
7. enabled bitCode
8. reinstalled cocoapods with brew

... but nothing works. Maybe you have an idea, what to do now?

Answer (score 1):

I spend hours on this, but all I had to do (again) was:

```
npm run tauri ios init
```